# Kinetic Energy with constant velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, velocity, dissipation

I am sorry for the question, but I am a noob in Physics.
I don't understand why in the kinetic energy's formula the distance is out of the equation.

Kinetic Energy formula:

$$K = \frac{1}{2}m v^2 = n J$$

For example: 
if I run $5$ miles at $3m/s$, I spend the same calories or joules ($J$) if I run for few meters with the same velocity. It is not like in the real life. 
I don't understand why. Any hints?

Comment: What you've written below the equation suggests that you're worried about why $distance$ doesn't appear in the equation. But above the equation you seem to be concerned about $mass$. Could you please clarify?

Comment: What is $n$ and $J$?

Comment: @garyp $n$ is a value and $J$ is Joule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kinetic energy is only part of the picture. If you were gliding in a perfect vacuum, your assessment would be right, it'd take the same amount of energy to travel different distances at the same speed (and it'd just take longer).  (Although even here, you're body wouldn't be perfectly efficient in converting it's chemical potential energy into kinetic energy, so the total energy spent would be greater than the kinetic energy gained, the rest of the energy would go to heat.)

Running here on earth, you have loss mechanisms such as friction and air resistance. In addition, at a run each stride is like a small jump, so a lot of energy is probably spent fighting gravity. Running for a longer time means you need to counter-act these forces for longer which takes more energy. To be really realistic you'd need to take into account how these forces varied with your speed, and take into account your biological efficiency at different speeds, etc. Intuitively, this is also why bikes take much less energy to go farther, you're minimizing several of the loss mechanisms.

As you can probably tell, a proper calculation of all these effects is very difficult. Physics at this level is just trying to give you a baseline to begin these calculations and give you some intuition for the underlying principles.

Answer (score 1):

As we I assume that( velocity =distance /time) internally they are related and we are moving means velocity is a measurable quantity. Not the distance taken as our prioty measurable quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Consieder you running. If an observer watch you from a very high distance you can be considered as material point. Let's also assume that you start and finish firm ($v=0$), and that the start and the finishing line coincide. So we have:
$$\Delta k=-\Delta U + W_{nc}$$
Where $W_{nc}$ is the work done by the non conservative force.
 $$\Delta k=\Delta U=0 \rightarrow W_{nc}=0 $$

We can also write $W_{nc}=W_{1}+W_{2}$ where $W_{1}$ is the work done by your legs and $W_{2}$ is the work done by forces which oppose your motion. So:
$$W_{1}+W_{2}=0$$
$W_{1}=F_{1}L$ and $W_{2}=F_{2}L$ If the forces are constant.

$$F_{1}=-F_{2}$$
Also $$P_{1}=F_{1}v$$ where $P_{1}$ is your power.

Now you must remember the first principle of thermodynamics for a system (closed):
$$\Delta U= Q-W$$
Now, assume that $Q=0 \rightarrow \Delta U=-W $
$$\Delta U=-F_{1}L$$
$$\Delta U=-P_{1}\Delta t$$
NOw if you run for 3 minutes with a power of 1000 W your internal energy decreases of 180KJ. 
NOw if you run for 10 minutes with a power of 1000 W your internal energy decreases of 600KJ, and you feel more tired.

Answer (score 1):

You are conflating work with energy, but there is a slight difference.

In fact: Work=*change in* Energy, i.e. U=ΔK.

Work is the accumulated force magnitude over distance along a path, so that an element of work dU=<**F**, **ds**>=F.ds.cos(θ) , where **ds**=elemental displacement along trajectory curve *S* , **F**=applied Force along *S*.

We integrate this and then call the upper and lower bounds "energy", or "kinetic energy" to be more specific, say K₁ and K₂, such that  ΔK=K₂-K₁.

So, we are really taking about "energy levels", at specific positions on the path, not a real-time formula that is calculated at every position.

These "energy levels" are really *potentials* , we could call them "work potentials", similar to the idea of "field potentials" e.g."voltage".

In order for work to actively exist , a force that provides *impetus* to the mass must exist, therefore the energy is not "carried" by the mass unlike have you have been taught, but work (actually "average force x distance") is "instructed" into the *structure* of the mass via *deformations* which results in *vibrations* .

These internal vibrations (that do internal "work") *reverb* inside the mass until they *dissipate* to the exterior environment. That can only happen if there's exterior masses *in contact* with the object at positions along it's trajectory, at which point the "kinetic energy" (work potential) is "released"(force is transmitted) into said masses, so that even a mass that is moving at a constant velocity will have *internal cyclical forces* within that provide *impetus* and therefore *inertia* to the structure of the mass.

Comment: To answer your specific example: Distance travelled S=5 miles, speed v=3m/s.                                                                                  
Case 1: Not interacting with the ground (suspended above, neglecting air resistance).                                                                                        
Your energy level is K=(½)M (3²)=4.5M Joules (if M is in kg). Case 2: Your foot impacts the ground and some of your momentum is transmitted to it resulting in an impulse, i.e. a force over time & a different energy level K'=(½)M ((3+Δv)²), where Δv=change in speed.

Comment: The work your body's mass M experiences with each impact (over distance ds) is:                                     
W=K'-K=ΔK=(½)M (6Δv+(Δv)²). Your initial speed was 3mps=3.28084 ydps. Say the stride length for is 2 strides per second, then your stride (Δs) is 3.28084 /2= 1.64042 yd. 5mi=8800yd=5364.48*Δs, so no. of impacts N=(#mi/Δs)(#Δs/ds)~ 5364.48*2~10729, total  ΣW ~N.ΔK~(10729)(½)M(6Δv+(Δv)²)~5364.48M(6Δv+Δv²). However, Δv alternates from + to - as the ground decelerates you back, so pretty much all the 6Δv terms cancel leaving ΣW~5364.48M((Δv)²). The Δv is along the arc of a circle.

Comment: From circular motion,Δ(v')/Δt~ (v')²/2R, where v'=v'(foot rel pelvis). R is length of your lower leg. If your stride is 3.28084 yd, your total leg is roughly then 2R=3.28084 yd /Δθ. 40 to 60 degrees is about max that your ankle can turn down whilst in contact with the ground, & 15 degrees up. Say R=0.55yd, then Δθ~3.28084/(2*0.55)~0.902 rads~51.69 deg, & if v(foot rel knee)=0.5v', Δv/Δt~3.281²/(4*0.55)~(4.893 )ydps². 0.5s per stride over Δs=1.64042 yd, divided by2 steps =>Δv~1.223125 ydps. Thus: ΣW~5364.48M((1.223125  ydps/0.9144 yd/m)²)~(15.693)M kiloJoules~3.75 M kcal, where M=mass in kg.

Comment: Worth a look. You could think of your legs as compound pendulums. That's why I used v & v'. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c9/Double-compound-pendulum-dimensioned.svg/1107px-Double-compound-pendulum-dimensioned.svg.png

Comment: To the Draft Science cult followers (a hermit guy on Youtube who doesn't believe in kinetic energy). KINETIC ENERGY for DUMMIES - VARIOUS EXPERIMENTS by STEPHEN BROUGH https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdwcRUamwh8

Comment: Thought this was funny. I put in M=90kg, and searched for the resulting kcal. This came up: https://www.frommfamily.com/products/dog/pate/can/ Looks like 1 can of dogfood will almost give you enough energy for the jog for that mass.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight   United States needs to go on a diet: Average (measured) male weight: 90.6 kg (199.7 lb); Average female weight: 77.5 kg (170.9 lb) Sample population /age range: 20+  ; Years: 2015-201 8

Comment: My calculation above doesn't seem to be particularly accurate, so I 'll try again with better data, using this site: https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/health/steps-miles.php. 3m/s=6.710809mph  and these stats: United States: Average (general) height:  170.1 cm (5 ft 7 in) ;male: 176.9 cm (5 ft 9 1⁄2 in) ;female:163.3 cm (5 ft 4 1⁄2 in)  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_human_height_by_country

Comment: Using a spread sheet with a range of data outputs from the app, I was able to extract a "steps taken over 5 miles" formula as a function of the pace (magnitude of velocity) v in mph: N(v)=16676.0399012627*EXP(-0.12224935693804* v). For v~6.71mph, N~7342. Here's the settings for the app: Distance 5 mi
Height 5ft 9in
Male/Female M
Mass (kg) 90